# It's About Time you Knew or It's about time you know

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, descriptive-grammar, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Would like to know which version is proper:

> - It's about time you know
> - It's about time you knew

---

Some examples:

- It's about time you know about a cancer diagnosis
- It's about time you knew about a cancer diagnosis

---

- It's about time you know if you have cancer
- It's about time you knew if you have cancer

---

- It's about time you know why you're feeling that way
- It's about time you knew why you're feeling that way

---

- It's about time you know what happened
- It's about time you knew what happened

Comment: _It's about time_ is normally used with the past tense - see [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-s-about-time).

Comment: Thank you.  So would you follow using the word knew or know?

Comment: @JoeV Past tense.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).